# Div elements on click fires for the first element only

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am listing my data in an ItemTemplate.Then inside the ItemTemplate, i have two div tags as follows:

```
   <ItemTemplate>
     <div id="contentdiv">
       <h4 id="titleresult"><a href="#"  onclick="showResults(<%#Eval("UserID")%>);return false;" class="title"><%# Server.HtmlEncode(Eval("Name").ToString())%></a></h4>
     </div>

     <div id="showclick" class=hideAll>
       <p class="brief"><%# Server.HtmlEncode(Eval("LegalName").ToString())%></p>
       <p class="brief"><%# Server.HtmlEncode(Eval("FirstName").ToString())%></p> 
       <p><%# Server.HtmlEncode(Eval("LastName").ToString())%></p>
     </div>
   </ItemTemplate>
```

Then i have the css to define the hideAll class so that when the page loads, the data in this div tag is hidden until the user clicks on the contentdiv link.

```
    .hideAll  { display:none }
    .displayAll { display:block; top:0px}
```

Then finally i have the javascript part for firing the click event.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function showResults(UserID) {
        var contentdiv= document.getElementById('contentdiv');
        var showclick = document.getElementById('showclick');

        <%
        long id =0;
        DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess();
        Data = dataAccess.GetCounterParty(id);

        %>
        var UserID = <%=dataAccess.GetCounterParty(id) %>
        contentdiv.style.visibility = "visible";
        $(showclick).removeClass('hideAll');
         }
  </script>
```

The UserID is the id of every element in the list. The problem is, the click affects only the first element no matter which other element i click on the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In html `id` is used to refer to one element.
If you use it multiple times the browser would default to the first element.

You should use a class selector. Something like:

```
$(".contentdiv").click(function(){
  $(this).next().removeClass('hideAll');
});
```

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/nunespascal/eS7Ph/). I used toggleClass though, it seems more appropriate to me.

Comment: Worked very well thank you. What if i want to hide the data again on clicking the title?

Answer (score 3):

An id is a unique identifier, you cannot have two or more things on the same page with the same identifier *and* expect things to work properly. Make your identifiers unique, and bind to the click event using a class selector instead.

Answer (score 0):

you should use class instead of id, id are unique, which only exist in 1 page, class can exist in multple div

some idea for u

```
html
<div class="showclick hideAll">

script
$('.showclick').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggle(); //toggle to show or hide, can be any element u want to toggle instead of this
});
```